# Find a projection of a $k$-simplex with minimal "radius"

Tags: regression, optimization, fitting

I asked the following question  on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/445987/35778) and I've been told that I may get more helpful answers here on Cross Validated. This is my first question here, so I hope the tags I've chosen are accurate enough.

> Let $S$ be a $k$-simplex in $\mathbb{R}^k$. I'd like to find a hyperplane $P$ that passes through the origin such that projections of vertices of $S$ onto $P$ are as close as possible to the origin (in minimax sense). The distances are measured in $\ell_2$-norm.
>
> I could only get trivial results for $k=2$, but even for $k=3$ I couldn't find a way to find a solution.
>
> Any hint on whether there is a polynomial-time algorithm that can solve this would be appreciated. If you know papers that are relevant I'd be thankful if you let me know.

Comment: Your question is relevant to this post, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/54687/how-can-a-vector-of-variables-represent-a-hyperplane, which is an interpretation of multiple regression in terms of hyperplane.

Comment: @semibruin Thank you, but that question doesn't seem to be very relevant.